# how to do bat file mysql

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have this code for how to do mysql bat file for backup, this is the code.

```
@echo off
echo Starting Backup of Mysql Database on server 
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dt=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a in ('echo %time%') do (set tm=%%a%%b%%c%%d)
set bkupfilename=%1 %dt% %tm%.sql
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%
mysqldump -p 3306 -h 192.168.0.1 -u root -p 123456 

bayanat>C:\mysql_daily_backups\"bayanat%bkupfilename%"
```

Comment: What's the wrong it generates empty sql file?

Comment: did you try with -p123456

Comment: Please check my edited answer, we must add a log to detect the problem origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

port must be with -P not -p (--port=port_num, -P port_num) and no space between -p and password

```
<-- snip -->
mysqldump -alv -P 3306 -h 192.168.0.1 -u root -p123456
bayanat 2> C:\mysql_daily_backups\output.log >C:\mysql_daily_backups\"bayanat%bkupfilename%"
```

Comment: Still the same problem empty sql file

Comment: I think you have problem in access to databse. did you try with local database

Comment: Yes, it's the same. what do you think.

Comment: what is the content of output.log?

Comment: Where can I find the output.log?

Comment: C:\mysql_daily_backups\

Comment: All of the files created are empty

Comment: are you sure that your database contains tables. please execute : show tables

Comment: Yes, it's huge schema, it has many tables. And how to execute showing tables.

Comment: The error in the output.log is.    -- Connecting to 192.168.0.1...
-- Retrieving table structure for table act_evt_log...
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)

Comment: f you have recently upgraded your MySQL version to 5.6, your mysqldump command will probably throw the following error:

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66765

Comment: How can I do backup specific tables?

Comment: add tables names after database name

mysqldump -alv -P 3306 -h 192.168.0.1 -u root -p123456
bayanat t1 t2 t3 2> C:\mysql_daily_backups\output.log >C:\mysql_daily_backups\"bayanat%bkupfilename%"